# Centos: php-devel trashed mysql

Tags: centos, php, mysql

Good morning.

I'm on a CentOS machine, did a

```
yum install php-devel
```

Flat out saying this

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

which couldn't finish since it complained about mysqld.sock

and now mysqld does not start at all, no matter what we do. Can anyone please lend a hand on WHERE should I look?

EDIT

Ok, we ended up doing a full server restore. Now, seeing as there are backups of all the files inside the /var/lib/mysql, how do I rebuild the mysql databases from those?

Comment: whats the output in /var/log/messages, what happens when you try running mysqld from the terminal rather than from /etc/init.d/mysqld?

Answer (score 0):

What was the complaint about mysql.sock? Can you paste the text?

First quick thing I'd try is make sure mysqld is not already running by executing "service mysqld stop" then "ps auxww | grep mysqld" to make sure nothing's left. At that point look to see if /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock still exists. If so, delete it, then try starting it up again.

Comment: It's not running, and I cannot find the exact complaint :S are there logs for that?

Comment: Did you see the error when you tried to start it? I'd try and start it up again, if so to see if it'll print the error again. Aside from that, You can try taking a look at the contents of /etc/init.d/mysqld to try and figure out the actual command it executes, and mimic it without the ">/dev/null 2>&1 &" part at the end.